# ConstraintLayout AHBottomNavigation animation problem

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with a navigation at bottom. In some cases i need to hide a bottom navigation with `ConstraintLayout` animation.

XML layout file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/lMainConstraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
. . .
toolbar and others views
. . .

<com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
                android:id="@+id/vNavigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To hide navigation by sliding to bottom:

```
  val newSet = ConstraintSet()
            newSet.clone(mInitialSet)
newSet.connect(R.id.toolbar, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        newSet.connect(R.id.vNavigation, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

            val transition = AutoTransition()
            transition.interpolator = AccelerateInterpolator()
            transition.duration = 250
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(lMainConstraint, transition)
            newSet.applyTo(lMainConstraint)
```

However, `vNavigation` hiding by half only. My `R.id.toolbar` at top hiding completely, any other `ViewGroup` hiding without any problems.

Putting `AHBottomNavigation` into `LinearLayout` or any other make no sense.

**Using library** - **com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.2.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is because the bottom of `AHBottomNavigation` is already constrained to the bottom of the parent by `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`. So when you add to new constraint by connecting the top of `AHBottomNavigation` with the bottom of the parent, it gets centered between those two constraints. Add `set.clear(R.id.vNavigation, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);` to your code and see if it works.

Comment: Yep, didn't notice my toolbar has no constraint to the top